# Couldn't match type Error while using `:` for lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, functional-programming

I want to write a program to find the first few rows of the Pascal Triangle.

This is the work I've done so far:

```
-- Gets the next row given the previous row
cur_row :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
cur_row x = ans where
            ans = zipWith (\a b -> a + b) (0 : x) (x : 0)

-- Gets the xth row
rows_helper :: Int -> [Integer]
rows_helper x
  | x == 1 = [1]
  | otherwise = cur_row (rows_helper (x - 1))

-- Main Function : Finds the first x rows of the Pascal's Triangle
rows :: Int -> [[Integer]]
rows x
  | x == 0 = []
  | x == 1 = [[1]]
  | otherwise = rows (x - 1) ++ [rows_helper(x)]
```

`rows` is the actual function that should return `x` rows of the Pascal Triangle.

`rows_helper` is meant to find the `x`th row of the Pascal Triangle.

To implement `rows_helper`, I need to implement `cur_row` which, from the previous row, returns the current row.

But, when I run it, I get

```
Couldn't match type ‘[Integer]’ with ‘Integer’
      Expected type: [Integer]
        Actual type: [[Integer]]
    • In the third argument of ‘zipWith’, namely ‘(x : 0)’
      In the expression: zipWith (\ a b -> a + b) (0 : x) (x : 0)
      In an equation for ‘ans’:
          ans = zipWith (\ a b -> a + b) (0 : x) (x : 0)
  |
5 |             ans = zipWith ( b -> a + b) (0 : x) (x : 0)
  |                                                    ^^^^^
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this. Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: `0` is not a list, you can't write `something : 0`. The syntax is `single_element : rest_of_list`. If you need to append at the end, you can use `list ++ [last_element]` (but note it can be slow, it costs O(N)).

Comment: @chi Okay, I didn't know that `:` operator works only for pre-adding. Thank you so much!